# Use Angular Router Resolver with Global Custom Error Handler

Tags: angular

In Angular, how to send `HTTP` error notifications from `Route Resolver` to `CustomErrorHandler`?

I've created a custom error handler as follows, and registered it in `NgModule`.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, PageNotFoundComponent],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: GlobalHttpErrorInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },
    {
      provide: ErrorHandler,
      useClass: CustomErrorHandler,
    },
  ],
```

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

  constructor(
    private snackbarService: SnackbarService,
    private ngZone: NgZone
  ) {}

  handleError(error: unknown): void {
    this.ngZone.run(() => {
      if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
        this.snackbarService.show(
          `Detected as error in global error handler from HTTP`,
          MessageTypeEnum.ERROR,
          10_000
        );
      } else {
        this.snackbarService.show(
          'Detected as error in global error handler. Please see the console!',
          MessageTypeEnum.ERROR,
          10_000
        );
      }
    });

    console.warn(error);
  }
}
```

```
@Injectable()
export class GlobalHttpErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<unknown>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      catchError((err) => {
        return throwError(() => {
          return err;
        });
      })
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see, I used a snackbar to show the error message
to users. The problem is when using Route Resolver as follows:

```
export const agamaGetByIDResolver: ResolveFn<any> = (
  route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot
): Observable<any> => {
  const id = Number(route.paramMap.get('id'));

  if (isNaN(id)) {
    const message = `Product id was not a number: ${id}`;
    return of(message);
  }

  if (!id) {
    const message = 'Missing required parameters of id  ';
    return of(message);
  }

  return inject(AgamaService)
    .getByID(id)
    .pipe(
      catchError((err) => {
        return throwError(() => {
          return err;
        });
      })
    );
};
```

What we want to achieve is: `CustomErrorHandler` will display the snackbar. But what happens is, Angular redirects to base_hrf by displaying blank_page?